# Proving $\big(n!^{\frac1n}\big)_{n\in\mathbb N^*} \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

By definition, for any $a\in\mathbb R$, there exists $k\in\mathbb N^*$ such that, if $n\in\mathbb N+k$, then $n!^{\large\frac1n}>a$. Therefore, by induction, I must:

- find some $k$ that satisfies $k!>a^k$;
- show that, for each $n\ge k$, if $n!>a^n$, then $(n+1)!>a^{n+1}$.

For the 2nd part, it's enough that $k\ge a-1$. I noticed the smallest adequate $k$ is $4$ for $a=2$ and $7$ for $a=3$, and I'm convinced that one can always find a $k$, but I would like a function of $a$ to make an actual argument.

Definition aside, methods other than this one are welcome. I tried picking a sequence dominated by $\big(n!^{\large\frac1n}\big)$ that went to infinity as well, but couldn't find any.

Comment: What's $\mathbb{N}^*$? Never seen this odd notation before.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}^\ast = \{0,1,2,\ldots\}-\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple but not-so-elegant proof.

Without loss, it is enough to prove the result for fixed natural a > 1. Showing that $(n!)^{1/n} > a$ eventually(ev.) is the same as showing 
$$n! > a^n  \quad\text{ev.} \iff x_n := \frac{n!}{a^n} > 1\quad\text{ev.}$$

For $n>a$,

$$x_n = \frac{a!}{a^a} \frac{n(n-1)…(a+1)}{a^{n-a}} $$

Every term on the top of the second fraction is at least a+1, and there are $n-(a+1)+1 = n-a$ terms, so

$$ x_n \geq \frac{a!}{a^a} \frac{(a+1)^{n-a}}{a^{n-a}} = \frac{a!}{a^a} \left( \frac{a+1}{a} \right)^{n-a} = C(a)  \left( \frac{a+1}{a} \right)^{n-a} $$
($C(a) = \frac{a!}{a^a} > 0$ is constant in $n$) which is bigger than 1 eventually, hence the result.

Comment: Makes sense, but that $a^{n−a}$ shouldn't be there, should it? I edited it out, feel free to rollback if needed.

Also, you assume $a\in\mathbb N$, but that's without loss too; one just has to replace $a$ with $\lfloor a\rfloor$.

Comment: I think what you want is $$x_n=\frac{a!}{a^{\color{#C00000}{a}}}\frac{n(n-1)\dots(a+1)}{a^{n-a}}$$ then $$x_n\ge C(a)\left(\frac{a+1}{a}\right)^{n\color{#C00000}{-a}}$$

Comment: thanks for the corrections, I've edited them in. I wanted to hide the factor $\left(\frac{a+1}{a}\right)^{-a}$ in  $\left(\frac{a+1}{a}\right)^{n-a}$ into $C(a)$ but I suppose that is not as clear as I thought.

Comment: You could do that with $$\frac{a!}{a^a}\left(\frac{a+1}{a}\right)^{n-a}=\frac{a!}{(a+1)^a}\left(\frac{a+1}{a}\right)^n$$

Answer (score 7):

When $n$ is even, $n/2$ of the numbers in the sequence $1,\ldots,n$ are greater than $n/2$. Therefore, $n! \geq (n/2)^{n/2}$, and this leads to the desired result.

Comment: Simple and clear. I was about to post this, until I saw it had already been. This should be the accepted answer, in my opinion. Note that it's also true that $n^{n/2} < n! ⇒ \sqrt{n} < n!^{1/n}$.

Answer (score 3):

Start with the logarithm of what we want
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1n\log(n!)
&=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\log(k)\\
&\ge\frac1n\int_1^n\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\log(n)-1+\frac1n
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left(n!\right)^{1/n}\ge\frac ne
$$

Answer (score 3):

Using AM-GM:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} +\cdots + \frac{1}{n}}{n} \ge \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n!}}$$
$$\sqrt[n]{n!} \ge \frac{n}{\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} +\cdots + \frac{1}{n}} = \frac{n}{H_n}$$

But since $H_n$ grows as $\ln x$ , we have (as $n\to\infty$):

$$\frac{n}{\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} +\cdots + \frac{1}{n}}  \to \infty$$

and therefore (as $n\to\infty$),

$$\sqrt[n]{n!} \to \infty$$

Answer (score 2):

Using Stirling's approximation, we have $n!> \sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n$.  Then $(n!)^{1/n}> \sqrt[n]{2\pi}n^{1/n} \frac{n}{e}$.  Since $\sqrt[n]{2\pi}\rightarrow 1$ and $n^{1/n}\rightarrow 1$ but $\frac{n}{e}\rightarrow \infty$, we see that $(n!)^{1/n}\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to prove: 
$$ \forall a > 0 \, \exists n \, \ni \, n! > a^n $$
which is equivalent to
$$ \forall a > 0 \, \exists n \, \ni \, \frac{a^n}{n!} < 1 \, .
$$
This last statement follows from the fact that
$$
e^a = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac {a^n}{n!}
$$
is convergent for all $ a > 0$.